# RHCSA Rapid Track Course (RH199) Online -vs- Classroom

Tags: redhat, centos7, rhel7

I just had a quick question about the differences associated with this. I understand that it is probably going to be extremely rare that a person took both, that is why I am hoping to get feedback from multiple people.

I see that online is 90 days (86 days longer).

***Does this allow you to review the same material multiple times, or is it setup so that once you go over a video it is no longer accessible?***

- If you could watch the same material multiple times over a period of time that is 20 times longer for $500 less this would seem like the obvious choice.

***What are your thoughts about this?***

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming or coding.

Comment: I would agree with you if I tagged this bash. However, I tagged this as Red Hat. I would recommend following a different tag if you only want programming or coding questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up calling Red Hat Support about this question. They assure me that this is possible however there is no feedback about questions that students may have whereas the classroom choice would have that.

In my mind the online option seems much better at this point.